# How to execute a sql server stored procedure using php script

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from my php script but I am running into some syntax problems.

I have an ODBC connection and I do not know the syntax used when doing a prepared statement for this.
I have found an example which uses `sqlserv_param` shown below but it does not fire.

The array being passed into php has this format:

```
SqlArr[empid,Wkend,Day,Title,Description,Value,Timestamp,AbbrevJob]
```

My DbConnectPSI has this following line of code to show you what kind of connection I am using.

```
$connect = odbc_connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};
            Server=$serverName;Database=$myDb", $userName, $myPass);
// Connection String in to SQL
```

Stored Procedure:

```
Alter PROCEDURE InsertfromPHP 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @paramEmpid int,
    @paramWkEnd Date,
    @paramDay Date,
    @paramTitle varchar(20),
    @paramDescription varchar(20),
    @paramValue float,
    @paramAbbrevJob int
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    If Exists (Select * from EmployeeTimeSheetsTemp where empid=@paramEmpid and Day=@paramDay  and Title=@paramTitle and Description=@paramDescription)
        Update EmployeeTimesheetsTemp set Value=@paramValue where empid=@paramEmpid and Day=@paramDay  and Title=@paramTitle and Description=@paramDescription
    Else
        Insert into EmployeeTimeSheetsTemp (Empid,WkEnd,Day,Title,Description,Value,Timestamp,AbbrevJob)
        Values(@paramEmpid,@paramWkEnd,@paramDay,@paramTitle,@paramDescription,@paramValue,getdate(),@paramAbbrevJob)
END
GO
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```
    <?php
    include_once 'DbConnectPSI.php';
        global $connect;
        global $record3;
        global $emptyQ;
        global $rightOn;
        global $SqlArr;
        global $i;
        $rightOn="Thank you, your time has been inserted successfully";
        $SqlArr = $_POST['SqlArr'];
            $tsql_callSP = "execute InsertfromPHP( ?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt3 = odbc_prepare( $connect, $tsql_callSP);
if($stmt3===false){throw new error exception(odbc_errormsg())}

            for ($i=0;$i<sizeof($SqlArr);$i++) {

                $empId = $SqlArr[$i][0];
                $WkEnd = $SqlArr[$i][1] ;
                $Day = $SqlArr[$i][2] ;
                $Title = $SqlArr[$i][3] ;
                $Description = $SqlArr[$i][4] ;
                $Value = $SqlArr[$i][5] ;
                $AbbrevJob = $SqlArr[$i][8] ;
                /*$params = array( 
                                 array($employeeId, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                                 array($WkEnd, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                                 array($Day, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                                 array($Title, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                                 array($Description, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                                 array($Value, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                                 array($AbbrevJob, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)  
                               );*/
                /* Execute the query. */

                $lego = odbc_execute($stmt3,array($Empid,$WkEnd,$Day,$Title,$Description,$Value,$AbbrevJob);
if($lego===false){throw new error exception(odbc_errormsg())}

            }
        odbc_close($connect);
        ?>
```

What syntax errors need to be fixed for this to work properly?

Can I do this in php since it works in sql server?

```
exec insertfromPHP @paramEmpId=89,@paramWkend='2015-10-24',@paramDay='2015-10-21',@paramTitle='1',@paramDescription='1',@paramValue=15,@paramAbbrevJob=3
```

but replace the concrete values with the sqlarr objects?

Error received:
[Error occuring at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6olSY.png)

Comment: Use `EXECUTE`, not `CALL`.

Comment: So i did change it from call insertfromPHP  to execute insertfromPHP but im guessing it did not fire, since no data was updated nor entered into the tbl...

Comment: Remove the curly brackets contained within the execute ... string.  It is highly probably that is your problem.  That said, what is the return value of the odbc_execute(), and are you actually checking it?  It returns `FALSE` on failure.   You should also add in your error checking logic, `odbc_error` and `odbc_errormsg` calls for details as to IF it fails.

Comment: Well I just keep executing a select statement for the table and I do not see any of the results I just entered from my javascript side which calls this php script. However When I take the stored procedure and run it in sql, it performs and data get inserted and updated if need be.

Comment: Many examples i looked at, included those curl brackets. But i did take them out but no response. If I just run my php script to see if it gives me any errors, but it does not. It gives me a notice but no errors.